# Displaying events for a specific user in a view ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-4

I am using Rails 4 and devise. I am trying to use an if statement in my 'myevents' view to only display the events that belong to the currently logged in user, can anybody help, currently it returns all the events and ignores the if statement. I also tried putting the if statement in the controller but no success there, here is my code:

///////////Myevents view

```
<h1>My Events</h1>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th><%= sortable "name" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "date" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "time" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "description" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "dresscode" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "price" %></th>
  </tr>

  <% @events.each do |event| %>
    <% if event.user_id == current_user %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= image_tag event.avatar.url %></td>
      <td><%= event.name %></td>
      <td><%= event.date %></td>
      <td><%= event.time %></td>
      <td><%= event.description %></td>
      <td><%= event.dresscode %></td>
      <td><%= event.price %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Show", event_path(event) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to "Edit", edit_event_path(event) %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', event_path(event),
                    method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
    </tr>
    <% else %>
    <%= puts "No events to display" %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

///////routes.rb declaration

```
get 'myevents', to: 'events#myevents'
```

////controller action

```
def myevents
   @events = Event.search(params[:search]).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
  end
```

Comment: Is this the condition for the if statement?

Answer (score 0):

The way you're fetching `Events` is wrong. Your models should be setup as so:

```
class User
  has_many :events
end

class Event
  belongs_to :user
end
```

#### controller

```
def myevents
  @events = current_user.events.search(params[:search).order(sort_column + " " + sort_direction).paginate(:per_page => 5, :page => params[:page])
end
```

#### view

```
<% if @events.any? %>
  # @events.each do |event|
<% else %>
  # no events
<% end %>
```